# Rebus-y Riddle-y thing

Tags: rebus

I have made a riddle that incorporates some rebus aspects. Hope you enjoy it!

AABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZINTERJECTION!SE-E

Hint:

> It's pretty hard to find the solution to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for a

> needle in a haystack

Explanations - thanks due to Marius!  - as the rebus may read like

> 'Need L in A Hey Stack' - from below:
>
>  Initial letter A = **A**
>  A-Z missing L = Need L  (**in** above A and below heh stack)
>  INTERJECTION! = **[hey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hey_(interjection))**
>  SE-E = StackExchange - Exchange = **Stack**

Hint: It's pretty hard to find the solution to this.

> This answer is a well known [idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+needle+in+a+haystack).

Comment: Good job! I was going for hey as the interjection, but everything is perfect :) The hint was to mean it's hard to find the solution so it's like looking for a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Thanks @G_as_in_Gnome for this and I updated heh to hey as it fits more nicely.

Comment: Nice work. And thanks for mentioning me in your academy award acceptance speech

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

> Splitting the letters for a better view
>  A ABCDEFGHIJK MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ INTERJECTION! SE-E
>  The **L** is missing.
>  So it could be something like `ANOL` then an interjection like `yey` or `oh` or something else. And `SE-E = S`.

Comment: Definitely on the right track :)

Comment: INTERJECTION + SE-E = INTERJECTION+S = INTERJECTIONS? *Mutiple of them?*

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> SE-E refers to stack exchange emacs .

Just read from google what is it

> Emacs /ˈiːmæks/ and its derivatives are a family of text editors that are characterized by their extensibility. The manual for the most widely used variant, GNU Emacs, describes it as "the extensible, customizable, self-documenting, real-time display editor".

It is editor , so you are using it type alphabets in it ??

Comment: Nope that's not it.